# Dropzone jquery - always using GET request, event it is set to POST

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm using the latest version of Dropzone.js -http://www.dropzonejs.com/
I prefer to use the script in an already defined  with some inputs.
So, based on the documentation, I turned off `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`
Immediately after that, I have

```
/*Image gallery */
    $(function () {

        $("div#file-image").dropzone({
            method: 'POST',
            url : "http://localhost:8080/profile/road-assistance/upload"
        });
    });
```

And the file-image div is like this:

```
<div id="images-container" class="ui-sortable dz-clickable">
   <div id="file-image" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red"></div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that even the method is a `POST`, the request is GET and I'm getting
`GET http://localhost:8080/bg/profile/road-assistance/upload 405 ()`

If I change the method to `PUT`, i'm getting an error with the `PUT` (which means that dropzone is properly initialized. Why it doesn't work with `POST`?

Comment: `405` is `Method Not Allowed` and `GET` isn't allowed, for me, this weird error was fixed by using `url` relative to `directory` or using without the port number `:8080` if providing full url. you can try it once providing url relative to the page where you are using dropzone. default method is already post you dont need to set it

Comment: Thanks, with relative url is working... super strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`405` is `Method Not Allowed` and GET isn't allowed, for me, this weird error was fixed by using URL relative to the directory or using without the port number `:8080` if providing full URL.

```
 $("div#file-image").dropzone({
     method: 'POST',
     url : "../profile/road-assistance/upload"
 });
```

Provide url relative to the page where you are using dropzone. The default method is already `post`, you dont need to set it.